# The String of an instance of a class becomes null. why? (dart flutter)

Tags: object, flutter, dart, instance

When I print q1 it's null. I expected to see the question printed.

```
void main() {
  Question q1 = Question(
      q: 'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.', a: false);

  print(q1.questionAnswer);

}

class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;
  Question({String q, bool a}) {
    q = questionText;
    a = questionAnswer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Should not you assign members instead of parameters? I mean questionText = q; questionAnswer = a;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try changing your constructor to

```
Question({String q, bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
```

Default value of any instance variable in dart will always be null.

So, in your case value of **questionText** and **questionAnswer** will also be null as everything in dart is an Object.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is by using the **this** keyword

```
class Question {
 String questionText;
 bool questionAnswer;

 Question({this.questionText, this.questionAnswer});
}
```

and then use it like this

```
void main() {
  Question q1 = Question(questionText: 'question text', questionAnswer: false);

  print(q1.questionAnswer);
}
```

[here is the dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/260d749efd9c0000619941f4717ccfd8)